# kryo serialization over storm

Tags: apache-storm, kryo

I need to serialize complex object (opencv:Mat) over apache storm (deployed in remote cluster). Can anyone suggest me a good tutorial custom kryo serialization or propose a solution on how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bean

```
     public class DataBean{

    Mat imageMatrix;
    int id;
    public DataBean(){

    }
    public DataBean(int id, Mat matrix) {
    setId(id);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Mat getImageMatrix() {
    return imageMatrix;
}
public void setImageMatrix(Mat matrix)
{
    this.imageMatrix=matrix;
}
```

}

Then I have created the serializer as follow:

```
      public class DataBeankryo extends Serializer<DataBean> implements Serializable{

    @Override
    public DataBean read(Kryo arg0, Input arg1, Class<DataBean> arg2) {
            DataBean bean=new DataBean();
            bean.setId(arg1.readInt());
            bean.setImageMatrix(arg0.readObject(arg1,org.opencv.core.Mat.class));
            return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Kryo arg0,  Output output, DataBean bean) {
            //arg0.register(org.opencv.core.Mat.class);
            output.writeInt(bean.getId());
            arg0.writeObject(output,bean.getImageMatrix(),arg0.getSerializer(org.opencv.core.Mat.class));
            //arg0.writeClassAndObject(output, bean);
            output.close();        }}
```

I hope this can help you!